# Attempt to invoke virtual method java.util.ArrayList using Bundle in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist, bundle

hi i'm trying to send ArrayList throw Bundle to Fragment and i have got this Problem (the problem is caused when getting the ArrayList) and i have tested before sending it's not null , 
 i have send it with

```
arg.putStringArrayList("lp", li);
```

and receive it with

```
ArrayList<String> lil = getArguments().getStringArrayList("lp");
```

and this is the StackTrace :

```
04-18 20:43:55.153  17577-17577/com.pfe.elmokhtar.domotique W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList android.os.Bundle.getStringArrayList(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
04-18 20:43:55.153  17577-17577/com.pfe.elmokhtar.domotique W/System.err﹕ at com.pfe.elmokhtar.domotique.DetailFragment.onCreateView(DetailFragment.java:31)
04-18 20:43:55.158  17577-17577/com.pfe.elmokhtar.domotique W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
04-18 20:43:55.158  17577-17577/com.pfe.elmokhtar.domotique W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
04-18 20:43:55.158  17577-17577/com.pfe.elmokhtar.domotique W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
04-18 20:43:55.158  17577-17577/com.pfe.elmokhtar.domotique W/System.err﹕ at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:833)
04-18 20:43:55.158  17577-17577/com.pfe.elmokhtar.domotique W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
04-18 20:43:55.160  17577-17577/com.pfe.elmokhtar.domotique W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:447)
04-18 20:43:55.160  17577-17577/com.pfe.elmokhtar.domotique W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-18 20:43:55.160  17577-17577/com.pfe.elmokhtar.domotique W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-18 20:43:55.160  17577-17577/com.pfe.elmokhtar.domotique W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-18 20:43:55.160  17577-17577/com.pfe.elmokhtar.domotique W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
04-18 20:43:55.160  17577-17577/com.pfe.elmokhtar.domotique W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-18 20:43:55.160  17577-17577/com.pfe.elmokhtar.domotique W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-18 20:43:55.160  17577-17577/com.pfe.elmokhtar.domotique W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
04-18 20:43:55.160  17577-17577/com.pfe.elmokhtar.domotique W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

and this is how i instanced the Fragment

```java
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
            dLayout.closeDrawers();
            Bundle arg = new Bundle();
            arg.putString("Menu", menu[position]);
            Fragment detail = new DetailFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, detail).commit();
            if (position == 0) {
            /*
            Pieces
             */
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                invokeWS();  //WebService Invocation it run fine

                arg.putStringArrayList("lp", li);
                if(li.isEmpty())
                    System.out.println("null Catched !");
            }
                /*
            Pieces
             */


            if (position == 5) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, CheckLoginActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        }
    });
```

and this is the Class detailfragment

```java
package com.pfe.elmokhtar.domotique;

/**
 * Created by elmokhtar on 3/11/15.
 */

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle args) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailfragment, container, false);
        //        TextView text= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail);
        ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        Bundle test = getArguments();
        //        String menu = getArguments().getString("Menu");
        try {

            ArrayList < String > lil = test.getStringArrayList("lp");
            System.out.println("done!");


            ArrayAdapter < String > adapter;
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lil);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //text.setText("test");
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Paste the code used to  instance the fragment and the code of DetailFragment.onCreateView()

Comment: i have updat the posted with detailfragment class and the fragment instance :)

Comment: You are not setting the fragment arguments. I can't find the piece of code where you run "arg.putStringArrayList("lp", li);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Fragment detail = new DetailFragment();
Bundle arg = new Bundle();
arg.putStringArrayList("lp", li);
detail.setArguments(arg);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, detail).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the arguments to the fragment, as i suggested in my comment:

```java
public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
    dLayout.closeDrawers();
    Bundle arg = new Bundle();
    arg.putString("Menu", menu[position]);
    arg.putStringArrayList("lp", li);
    Fragment detail = new DetailFragment();
    detail.setArguments(arg);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, detail).commit();
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) i just move it 
detail.setArguments(args);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, detail).commit();
to the end of the method ^^

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to create instance of fragment and passing values to it

**Activity** : create Fragment instance like this

```
Fragment detail=DetailFragment.newInstace(li);
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, detail).commit();
```

**Fragment** : Always create a **default constructor** for fragments

> All subclasses of Fragment must include a public no-argument constructor.

```
 public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

        public DetailFragment() {
        }

        public static Fragment newInstace(ArrayList<String> items) {
            Fragment fragment = new DetailFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putStringArrayList("key", items);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return fragment;
        }

        //your stuff

    }
```